# How to align any element in center?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, center

I have given fix `width:350px;` to div element and want to show in the center of the screen. I have used `margin:auto;` property. But, still I am not able to do the same. Please advise.

Comment: Did you search for "vertical centering"? Please show your current HTML/CSS code in a snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center an element vertically and horizontally

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">TEXT</div>
</div>

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Your container must have a height I recommend

Answer (score 0):

This will work ...

```css
.center {width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: auto; background: #f00;}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

But you need to check there should not be any `float` property in your element..!